# Wordpress Jet Appointment custom schedule but global work time

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm a beginner with Wordpress, PHP and all this stuff

I want to make a appointment service with different product and different duration, I would like that people can choose the start time ( on working time, like 8h-9h , 8h30-9h30....), and I wan't to ease the modification of opening hours

I work on existing webiste with Elementor and Jet Appointment, actually I manage to do it but on each product I must choose "Use Custom Schedule" option to set the duration time of the product, and it show the Work Hours panel, and I must set the fields otherwise the website show blank work hours, and it's not changing with global setting work hours... I show you on images

[image: empty work time]
[image: product settings]

How can I find a solution ? (also I wanted to change "Work time" and "Start" item to another langage if it's possible)